# Displaying image from PostgreSQL database, bytea

Tags: java, image, postgresql

This code takes picture test.gif and puts the picture bit value into a bytea coloumn.

```
public void addImage() throws SQLException, IOException {
    Connection con = openConnection();

    File file = new File("test.gif");
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO image VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
    ps.setString(1, file.getName());
    ps.setBinaryStream(2, fis, (int)file.length());
    ps.setInt(3,1);
    ps.executeUpdate();
    fis.close();

}
```

My next goal is to display the picture that is saved in the database in bytes. How can this be done ?

Comment: Display the picture where? webpage, swing app etc?

Comment: Display picture in a swing app. The program is actually comand based in Comand Prompt, sow there should be a simpel swing program that shows the picture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like:

```
// Run a query again the IMAGE table to fetch the image with the given id
public Image readImage(Connection conn, int id) throws SQLException {
  PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
  try {
    pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT contents FROM image WHERE id = ?");
    pstmt.setInt(1, id); 
    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
    if (rs.next()) {
      InputStream is = rs.getBinaryStream(1);
      return ImageIO.read(is);
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  } finally {
    if (pstmt != null) {
      try {
        pstmt.close();
      } catch (SQLException ignored) {
      }
    }
  }
}

// Display the given Image on a Swing frame
public void showImage(final Image img) {
  JFrame frame = new JFrame("Image");
  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  frame.setSize(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight());
  frame.add(new JPanel() {
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
      g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
    }
  });
  frame.show();
}
```

might work for you.