# convert Blob into a bytea in java

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, postgresql-9.1

I'm working in postgresql database , i need to convert a MYSQL Blob datatype into a PostgreSQL bytea using java code only is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//(assuming you have a ResultSet named RS)
PreparedStatement psMySql = connMySql.prepareStatement("select myBlob from myTable where ...");
Blob blob = rs.getBlob("myBlob");

int blobLength = (int) blob.length();  
byte[] blobAsBytes = blob.getBytes(1, blobLength);

PreparedStatement psPostresql = connPostgresql.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO myNewTable VALUES (?, ?)");
psPostresql.setString(1, myId);
psPostresql.setBytes(2, blobAsBytes);
psPostresql.executeUpdate();

//release the blob and free up memory.
blob.free();
```

Comment: using the above code i have convert Blob into a bytea in java, but now im not able to fetch the bytea from postgresql, i try to retrive as per this link http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.2/static/jdbc-binary-data.html

Comment: it will document,ppt,excel,images

Comment: it will store document,when i try to retrive I'm getting numbers like 314530413142313141 in the file

Comment: @Stahish : so if you try to retrieve it as a File, if you open the File it doesn't work ?

Comment: after retrive the file when i try to open , the file contains only numbers like 314530413142313141

Comment: @Stahish : Ok, first, when you get the Blob from mySql, are you able to save it into a File and open it ? If yes, can you from the File you've created, store it into Postresql, retrieve it from Postgresql in a new File and then open it again ? If yes again, it means that the part byte[] didn't work well, else you'll know where your error is.

Comment: i've createda file and store it into Postresql,then i retrieve it from Postgresql the file contains only numbers like 314530413142313141 i think the issue is with the postgresql and bytea any solution for this?

Comment: @Sathish : try with this sample : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6078525/displaying-image-from-postgresql-database-bytea with an image and tell me if it works.

Comment: @Sathish you have the last driver version ? Else, instead of setBytes, can you try with a SetBinaryStream and a getBinaryStream ?

Comment: setBinaryStream only i have used buddy, this is my driver version postgresql-8.3-603.jdbc3.jar

Comment: @Sathish : did you try with the LargeObject API ? http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.3/static/jdbc-binary-data.html at the end of the article. Store it with it, and get it back with it too, and try to open your file.

Comment: ya yes buddy LargeObject API  works fine already tried, but i need bytea now

Comment: @Sathish Ok mate ... well, then, if it doesn't work only with bytea, I'm sorry I can't help more, I have no postgresql database on my desk ... Maybe someone with postgresql on his/her desk will find a solution for you ! Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know both support JDBC drivers. And JDBC has a standard way with dealing with BLOBs. I'm doing it all the time in DB2.

So:

- connect to MySQL
- do a select. Let's say the blob column is FIELD_BLOB
- rs.getBytes("FIELD_BLOB")
- connect to Postgres
- do a PreparedStatement
- call setBytes on this preparestatement passing in bytes you got from MySQL

If getBytes, setBytes does not work, try using input and output streams.