# Updating JLabel via SetIcon from bytea data type in postgres

Tags: java, postgresql

I am retrieving gif images from Wolfram|Alpha.  In an effort to minimize queries I want to store those images and only query W|A when the data is changed, so I am storing the images as a `bytea` data type in my postgres db.  The "save" portion seems to be working because there is data.  `System.out.println(rs.getString("fnPlotImg"))` yields this:  `\x4275666665726564496d6167654035356437373834323a2074797065203d203120446972656374436f6c6f724d6f64656c3a20726d61736b3d66663030303020676d61736b3d6666303020626d61736b3d666620616d61736b3d3020496e7465676572496e7465726c65617665645261737465723a207769647468203d2032303020686569676874203d20313335202342616e6473203d203320784f6666203d203020794f6666203d203020646174614f66667365745b305d2030`

I have been able to successfully update the image from W|A using this bit of code:

```
String path = ((WAImage) element).getURL();
URL url = new URL(path);
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(url);
picLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image));
```

I would like to update my application with the image from the database and have attempted this code:

```
byte[] ba = rs.getBytes("fnPlotImg");
try{
    picLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ba));
} catch (NullPointerException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

My rationale is that bytea is a byte array, getBytes() is supposed to retrieve a byte array, and ImageIcon() is supposed to handle a byte array.However, if I don't build in a null pointer exception it errors out.  I presume this is because I am not saving the image to DB correctly or I am not retrieving it correctly.

All thoughts are welcome, I'm getting fatigued so I'll check in the morning with fresh eyes.

Comment: How are you storing the image in the database?

Comment: Inserting it via SQL with related data as a BufferedImage... it occurs to me that I didn't check to see if this was the right thing to do.

Comment: I'm think you want to write the file image data, not the `BufferedImage`, something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6078525/displaying-image-from-postgresql-database-bytea) for example.  This way you just read the `bytea`, `InputStream` through `ImageIO`

Comment: I'll try your suggestion in the morning, thank you for the input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have a installation of PostgreSQL available, but I think you should be writing/reading the image format and not the `BufferedImage` data.

For example, writing might look something like...

```
Connection con = ...;
BufferedImage img = ...;
try (PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("insert into tableofimages (image) values (?)")) {
    try (ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
        ImageIO.write(img, "png", baos);
        try (ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray())) {
            stmt.setBinaryStream(1, bais);
            int rows = stmt.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println(rows + " rows updated");
        }
    }
} catch (SQLException | IOException exp) {
    exp.printStackTrace();
}
```

And reading might look something like...

```
Connection con = ...;
try (PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("select image from tableofimages")) {
    try (ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()) {
        while (rs.next()) {
            try (InputStream is = rs.getBinaryStream(1)) {
                BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(is);
            }
        }
    }
} catch (SQLException | IOException exp) {
    exp.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I finally got to this.  The "write" portion of this solution, and many like it that I have found, are writing the image by itself to a table without any concurrent data.  I assume that setBinaryStream will write only the image and if I want to do an insert on more than just the image column I have to do an insert of all the initial data, then an update of the BLOB column, or vice-versa.  Does this sound right, or can I write everything at once somehow?

Comment: You could just expand the insert to have multiple values and set each marker (?) with the value you want inserted, so should be able to do in a single step.  You could also update the table as normal as well

Comment: OK, I didn't understand how the PreparedStatement worked.  Makes sense.  But now when I write to then read from the DB it comes back all black.  I might need to break it down step by step to find the issue, that'll take some time.

Comment: You really should learn, have a look [Using Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Comment: I ran the (updated) code through H2 (against a BINARY type, which should be the same as BYTEA) and it seems to have worked for me.  The original code was using column `0` when reading the binary stream, when it should have been reading `1`

Comment: I gave you the credit for the answer, though I'm struggling with the image coming back all black.  I think that's a separate problem.

Comment: Disregard, I solved it.  I was "storing" the image in a JLabel, then extracting it.  This caused a conversion, of sorts, causing the pixelbits to drop from 8 to 1 (among other weirdness).  I created a `Private BufferedImage` within the class instead of storing it in the JLabel and that fixed it.  Thanks for the help!