# Retrieving file data from database

Tags: java, sql, postgresql-9.4

I am trying to get file data from database to HTML using a Java servlet.
The file data is in binary format. I am converting binary format data to string format, but I am getting error as:

> The column index is out of range: 1, number of columns: 0.

Can anyone please suggest me where I am going wrong?

Here is my Java code:

```
package fileretrieve;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.Part;

import org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.IOUtils;

import dbConnection.Dbconn;

@MultipartConfig
public class FileRetrieve extends HttpServlet {



    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String onelevel = request.getParameter("onelevel");
        String twolevel = request.getParameter("twolevel");
        String threelevel = request.getParameter("threelevel");
        String fourlevel = request.getParameter("fourlevel");
        String fivelevel = request.getParameter("fivelevel");
        String sevenlevel = request.getParameter("sevenlevel");
        String eightlevel = request.getParameter("eightlevel");


        Part filePart = request.getPart("data");


        byte[] filecontent1 = new byte[] {78,73, 67,69,70,75,80,76,68};
        String value = new String(filecontent1);
       System.out.println(value);



        Connection conn = null; // connection to the database
        String message = null;
        Statement st = null;// message will be sent back to client

        try {
            // connects to the database
              conn = Dbconn.getConnection();
              st = conn.createStatement();

            // constructs SQL statement
            String sql = "Select data from files1 where board=?,syllabus=?,class=?,chapters=?,state=?,terms=?";
            PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            statement.setString(1, onelevel);
            statement.setString(2, twolevel);
            statement.setString(3, threelevel);
            statement.setString(4, fourlevel);
            statement.setString(5, fivelevel);
            statement.setBytes(6, filecontent1);
            statement.setBytes(7, filecontent1);
            statement.setBytes(8, filecontent1);





           /* if (inputStream != null) {
                // fetches input stream of the upload file for the blob column
                statement.setBlob(6, inputStream);
            }
 */

//            statement.setBinaryStream(6, fis, (int)file.length());
            // sends the statement to the database server
            int row = statement.executeUpdate();

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            message = "ERROR: " + ex.getMessage();
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                // closes the database connection
                try {
                    conn.close();
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            // sets the message in request scope
            request.setAttribute("Message", message);

            // forwards to the message page
            getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/home.html").forward(request, response);
        }
    }
}
```

Database table:

```
CREATE TABLE files1
(
  board text,
  syllabus text,
  class text,
  subject text,
  chapters text,
  data bytea,
  state text,
  terms text
)
```

Comment: This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32623165/updating-jlabel-via-seticon-from-bytea-data-type-in-postgres/32623457#32623457) demonstrates writing a image (from memory) to the database, but the basic process should be the same

Comment: Actually I am retrieving file data from database. As image or file both will be stored in blob or bytea.

Comment: That's fine, it's just binary data - I'd recommend reading the binary stream from the database and saving it to a temporary file

Answer (score 1):

You have 8 parameters but query has only 6 (section where)

Comment: Ok I added one more parameter in query and now my query is        
String sql = "Select data from files1 where board=?,syllabus=?,class=?,subjects=?,chapters=?,state=?,terms=?"; Now I am getting error as                                                                                                                       The column index is out of range: 8, number of columns: 7.

Comment: I didnt get you.Can you please explain me what do u mean

Comment: You have query `"Select data from files1 where board=?,syllabus=?,class=?,chapters=?,state=?,terms=?";`
there are 6 symbols **?**
and than you try to set 8 parameters
`statement.setString(1, onelevel);  
statement.setString(2, twolevel);  
statement.setString(3, threelevel);  
statement.setString(4, fourlevel);  
statement.setString(5, fivelevel);  
statement.setBytes(6, filecontent1);  
   statement.setBytes(7, filecontent1);  
   statement.setBytes(8, filecontent1);`  
you must add 2 symbols **?** or remove 2 parameters

Comment: If I remove 2 parameters seven, eightlevels  then again I am getting error as The column index is out of range: 5, number of columns: 4

Comment: Not understanding how to query. Based on other 7 parameters I am trying to retrieve data from database.

Comment: just try to remove this `statement.setBytes(7, filecontent1);           
 statement.setBytes(8, filecontent1);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154766/discussion-between-vitalii-and-radha-madhavi).

Comment: So, did you get positive result?

Comment: But my binary stream data is not converting to string format